# Problem with NinePatchDrawable

Tags: android

The problem with NinePatchDrawable. Created 9.png file using a utility draw9patch, but when the throw the file in a folder res/drawable error: No resource found that matches the given name.

Comment: how did you call the file and how do you refer to it in your code?

Comment: I do not write code, I just move the file to a folder res/drawable and once an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

what is the file named? Resource file names can only have lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores with no spaces.

Comment: Original file: test.png, the second file: test.9.png. They are in a folder res/drawable. Version SDK 1.6. This can cause the error?

Comment: No, those look good. Where exactly are you getting that error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the .png to the file name?

```
android:drawable="@drawable/9"
```

will work but

```
android:drawable="@drawable/9.png"
```

will NOT work

Comment: Original file: test.png, the second file: test.9.png.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you can't have test.png and test.9.png in the same folder. You must remove the test.png once you have "9-patched" it. Because for the system, it refers to the same image.